ESP32-s3 master i2c guru meditation error
Basically, I'm using two ESP32-s3 to communicate with each other through i2c. For the slave ESP32, I have no problem with using the same method as how the master ESP32 is trying to read. I get the following error when I attached interrupt to read what the slave ESP32 is sending out.
Guru Meditation Error: Core  0 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU0). 

If I disable interrupt, the error message doesn't pop up. However, I needed interrupt, as my master ESP32 should process other stuffs and on the meantime and retrieve the data sent by the slave at the time it does. The followings are the code that are giving the issue. Basically I'm currently just looping the function i2c_read_di(). It would be very much appreciated if anyone could give me any suggestions regarding it. Thanks!
Interrupt Function:
static IRAM_ATTR bool i2c_master_rx_done_callback(i2c_master_dev_handle_t channel, const i2c_master_event_data_t *edata, void *user_data)
{
    BaseType_t high_task_wakeup = pdFALSE;
    QueueHandle_t receive_queue = (QueueHandle_t)user_data;
    xQueueSendFromISR(receive_queue, edata, &high_task_wakeup);
    return high_task_wakeup == pdTRUE;
}

uint32_t i2c_master::i2c_read_DI() {
    if (ret != ESP_OK) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to transmit read DI command");
        return 0;
    }
    uint8_t* data_rcv = (uint8_t *)(malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)));
 
    QueueHandle_t receive_queue = xQueueCreate(1, sizeof(i2c_master_event_data_t));
    if (receive_queue == NULL) {
        free(data_rcv);
        ESP_LOGE("I2C", "Failed to create queue");
        return 0;
    }
 
    cbs.on_trans_done = i2c_master_rx_done_callback;
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(i2c_master_register_event_callbacks(i2c_master_handle, &cbs, receive_queue));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(i2c_master_receive(i2c_master_handle, data_rcv, 1, -1));
 
    i2c_master_event_data_t rx_data;
 
   if (diCnt == 0) {
        DI_fromSlave = 0;
        esp_err_t ret = i2c_master_transmit(i2c_master_handle, DI_cmd, sizeof(DI_cmd), portMAX_DELAY); // Consider using a specific timeout instead of portMAX_DELAY
        if (ret != ESP_OK) {
            ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to transmit read DI command");
            return 0;
        }
        diCnt++;
    }      
 
    if (xQueueReceive(receive_queue, &rx_data, pdMS_TO_TICKS(100)) == pdPASS) {
        if(diCnt == 1) {
            ESP_LOGI("I2C", "Data received 1: %d", *data_rcv);
            DI_fromSlave |= ((uint32_t)(*data_rcv)) << 16;
            diCnt++;
        }
        else if(diCnt == 2) {
            ESP_LOGI("I2C", "Data received 2: %d", *data_rcv);
            DI_fromSlave |= ((uint32_t)(*data_rcv)) << 8;
            diCnt++;
        }
        else if(diCnt == 3) {
            ESP_LOGI("I2C", "Data received 3: %d", *data_rcv);
            DI_fromSlave |= ((uint32_t)(*data_rcv));
            diCnt = 0;
            printf("DI from slave: 0x%06lX\n", DI_fromSlave);
            free(data_rcv);
            vQueueDelete(receive_queue);
            return DI_fromSlave;
        }
    }
    else {
        ESP_LOGE("I2C", "Failed to receive data");
        return 0;
    }
    free(data_rcv); // free allocated memory
    vQueueDelete(receive_queue); // delete the queue to free resources
 
    return ESP_OK;
}

